# Make a QGIS project stored on postgresql read only for specific users

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I would like to restrain the privileges of certain users of my QGIS project stored on my PostgreSQL database to certain users.

I would like to make it read-only for everyone but myself.

Other users would still be able to modify the PostgreSQL tables but not the project itself (styles, connections, layers, etc.)

Comment: I didn't test it on the QGIS project table, but maybe a hint : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: You've got two different security models here, with two very different goals. You need to use different technologies to prevent end users from modifying symbology.

Comment: To these users, do not allow them to do create/update/remove in the `qgis_projects` table. These users will still be able to edit GIS layers stored

Comment: I'm already using rowsecurity for restraining access privileges on table data. The goal here is to have a qgis project stored on my postgresql server that end users can use to do basic work (querys, map exports, etc) but no changes to symbology, forms, layer order, layers, print layouts and so on.  That way I only have to do structural updates to this project instead of working with styles stored on postgres and so on. That way everybody is always using the last updated version of the project without having to remind users to load the latest styles and so on.